# AWS API Gateway MTLS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mtls

I have a problem with the implementation of an API Gateway on AWS with Mutual TLS authentication,

I have a custom domain attached to the API Gateway, the instance is configured with load balancer nginx,

custom domain ex: app.sandbox.domain.com

the mutual TLS function on the custom domain

but when I go through the environment url
environment url ex: http://app-sandbox.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

mutual TLS authentication does not apply.

Comment: `app-sandbox.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` check if it's getting resolved. a lot of times we tend to forget to create route53 entry for custom domain  which should resolve to API Gateway endpoint

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the question you're asking or problem you're having. Your current title is a meaningless repetition of the information already available in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title is useless in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the default endpoint on the API GW - only if it's an HTTP API. This will force mTLS for requests to the endpoint.